# @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ID) can't display the right value

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have   a model contain the file XSID（Guid） and ID（nvarchar）, Now I want to edit the ID value with @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ID) but it could not get the right value ,it also get the value of XSID .But the @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ID) could get the right value.
I don't konw why?

```
@using Student.Resource;
@using M = Student.Model;
@model M.Stu_XS

    <ul class="cur">
          <li class="line">
               <label>
                     @Stu_XS.ID：
                </label>
               <span>
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.XSID)
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ID)
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ID)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ID)
               </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an ID in your route, that value will be used and not the one in your model.

For example let's suppose that you have the following model:

```
public class Stu_XS
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Guid XSID { get; set; }
}
```

and the following controller action:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(int id)
{
    var model = new Stu_XS();
    model.ID = 123;
    return View(model);
}
```

which you would request like this:

```
/somecontroller/someaction/456
```

The `Html.EditorFor` will display `456` which is coming from the route and not `123` from the model. That's by design. If you want to change this behavior you will have to remove the `ID` from the `ModelState` so that the value from your model is used:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(int id)
{
    var model = new Stu_XS();
    model.ID = 123;
    ModelState.Remove("id");
    return View(model);
}
```